# Chinese remainder theorem corollary.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I was puzzled regarding corollary 31.29 of the Chinese remainder theorem as presented in the chapter on number theoretic algorithms by Cormen et al. I found another person who asked the same question [here](http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-prove-this-corollary-of-Chinese-remainder-theorem). When I look at the answer though, it doesn't make sense to me. It is said that "if a=b(mod n) then a=b(mod n_i) for any n_i|n. But, if n>n_i, then a from the first equation can take n values while the a in the second equation can take only n_i values. So, how can this hold in general? Here is what I think is a counter example -

> 100%%55 = 
>   45
>
> 100%%11=
>   1

Here, b=100, n=55 and n_i=11 (right?). So how come the two equations don't produce the same result as the statement says they should?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no probem here, as
$$
45 = 1\mod 11
$$
or in other words:
$$
1 + 11\Bbb Z = 45 + 11\Bbb Z
$$

---

The proof is actually easy: if $a=b\mod n$ then $n|(a-b)$, and if $n_i|n$ then, as the relation "divides" is transitive, $n_i|(a-b)$ as well. So $a=b\mod n_i$.